# CSS: Combination of overflow-y: visible and overflow-x: hidden ignored on parent element; Dropdown is causing unwanted scrollbar

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a table with a width bigger than it's parent. To display all the content I'm using overflow-x: scroll.
Inside the table there is a td with a dropdown button, which triggers a dropdown box. This dropdown box has a positon of absolute and the parent container has a positon of relative. However when the dropdown box appears it extends the height of the table, ignores the overflow-y: visible and causes an unwanted scrollbar to appear on the parent.

The wanted result is that I keep the scrollbar on the x-axis and the dropdown box is visible outside of the table.

Checkout [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fds2L49n/44/) where I recreated the problem or see the snippet below.

```css
main {
  width: 1000px;  
}

.table-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

table {
  min-width: 1200px;
}

tr {
  height: 50px;
}

.btn-actions {
  position: relative;
}

a.dropdown-btn:hover + .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown {
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown > a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Test description</td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-actions">
            <a class="dropdown-btn" href="#">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <a>Test 1</a>
              <a>Test 2</a>
              <a>Test 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</main>
```

Comment: I've played a lot with the  code and actually what you want is not possible. On one hand you want <div class="table-wrapper"> to have 'overflow-x: scroll', but on the other hand you want it to be 'overflow-x: visible'. I'd suggest to let users either use the browser horizontal scroll for the table or to search for a solution with Javascript.